# How to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How to use a list of strings [which may contain any character] as keys? [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527961/how-to-use-a-list-of-strings-which-may-contain-any-character-as-keys)

Well to put it frankly - I have no idea how to make this clearer. I wish to use a list as key for a dictionary in python, so what is the unclarity in that question? My other question about this seems to come over as a rant, Strange how people completely misunderstand me.

I could put this pseudocode in it, but that's silly - and bugs are potentially attracting more attention than algorithmic importance.

```
namelist = sorted(["Jan", "Frank", "Kim"])
commonTrait = newTraits()
traitdict = {}
traitdict[namelist] = commonTrait;

//later I wish to retrieve it:
trait = traitdict[sorted(["Jan", "Frank", "Kim"])]
```

But how is that more clean - I can't really see the difference between simply asking above question & putting this simple code in there.
As a ps: the answer is already given in such a way I may work it further out myself (even better then that) so should I still try to get it reopened?

Comment: Yes, you should put that code in there, it makes it very clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "???" is what makes (inquiries come over as a rant) the difference between asking and demanding. People are sensitive to that here (and probably elsewhere, and for good reason, imho).

Comment: Funny so I clear up any confusion and it still getting downvotes, is that called the "bandwagon"? - Can i request removal of voting/my name from that question? Or can someone please explain what I should still improve?